# Azure build pipelines - using the 'DownloadSecureFile' task within a template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure DevOps project with a couple of YAML build pipelines that share a common template for some of their tasks.

I now want to add a `DownloadSecureFile` task to that template, but I can't find a way to get it to work.
The following snippet results in an error when added to the template, but works fine in the parent pipeline definition (Assuming I also replace the `${{ xx }}` syntax for the variable names with the `$(xx)` version):

```
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  name: securezip
  displayName: Download latest files
  inputs:
    secureFile: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    retryCount: 5
  
- task: ExtractFiles@1
  displayName: Extract files
  inputs:
    archiveFilePatterns: ${{ variables.securezip.secureFilePath }}
    destinationFolder: '${{ parameters.sourcesDir }}\secure\'
    cleanDestinationFolder: true
```

The error occurs on the 'Extract File' step and is `Input required: archiveFilePatterns`, so it looks like it's just not finding the variable.

As a workaround, I could move the download task to the parent pipeline scripts and pass the file path as a parameter. However, that means duplicating the task, which seems like a bit of a hack.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Is the problem that `DownloadSecureFile` is failing, as stated? Or is the problem that the following `ExtractFiles` step is failing?

Comment: The `DownloadSecureFile` task is working. I just can't seem to access the variable that holds the location of the downloaded file.

Comment: Okay, I cringe to ask this, but have you defined `securezip` as a variable in the template? I wonder if you're defining a task variable but trying to reference a template variable and those aren't the same thing.

Comment: @catfood Thanks for the suggestion, I haven't defined any variables. But I wouldn't normally need to. The `DownloadSecureFile` task automatically puts the value into a variable. perhaps I'm just trying to access it incorrectly though? Normally (outside a template), I would just use `$(securezip.secureFilePath)`. If I try that inside the template, it fails to even start executing though.

Comment: I can't help noticing that in your question you're naming the first task `scurezip` (with one E) but accessing a variable called `securezip` (with two Es) in the second task.

Comment: Ah, that's a typo, the name in the script isn't actually securezip. I have checked the spelling of the real variables though and it's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables in dollar-double-curly-brackets are resolved at template expansion time. They are not the output of tasks.

Output variables from tasks are referenced by dollar-single-parentheses and they don't need to start with the word "variables."

So I believe the line you're looking for is like this, and it isn't affected by the template mechanism.

```
    archiveFilePatterns: $(securezip.secureFilePath)
```

Comment: You are correct! I was under the impression that the dollar-single-parentheses notation didn't work within templates. Clearly, that's not the case.